# MySQL UPDATE and DELETE Conundrum

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, equals

I've got a table with two column: `applicationid` and `studentid`. I want to update `applicationid` to a new value where `applicationid` is equal to an old value and `studentid` is not equal to (`studentid` where `applicationid` is already equal to the new value). The table looks like this, and I want to update the 2222222222222 `applicationid` to 1111111111111, but not always:

```
--applicationid-- --studentid--
--1111111111111-- --111111111-- // RIGHT HERE!
--1111111111111-- --555555555--
--2222222222222-- --666666666-- // Here I want to simply update application id to 1111111111111
--2222222222222-- --111111111-- // I WANT TO DELETE THIS ROW, BECAUSE THE UPDATE RESULT ALREADY EXISTS! ^^ 
--2222222222222-- --777777777-- // I also want this row to be updated.
```

This is the query I've got, but it does update `applicationid` to the new value, even if the result already exists:

```
UPDATE students_applications 
SET applicationid = 1111111111111 
WHERE applicationid = 2222222222222
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
delete from table where studentid = '111111111' and applicationid <> '111111111111111';
update table set applicationid = '11111111111111';
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. The only data I have is the two applicationids that I want to modify, but they are enough. I want to update applicationid in rows that the combination of studentid and the new applicationid still doesn't exit, and delete the rows that the combination of their studentid and the new applicationid does exist.